# authentication with react + localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, async-await, local-storage

I write following code to authenticate with react but have one problem. after user logged in,  set token in local storage and redirect the user to the dashboard and in this page check token from local storage and if not exist redirect the user to the login page and my problem is here!! when come in dashboard page can't get token because return null to me but if refresh the page return token!!

In fact, I'm can't get token after set that.

My codes is:

```
export const userLogin = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.post(API.USER_LOGIN,data).then((response) => {
            dispatch(loginSuccess());
            setToken(response.data.token);
            dispatch(setUserToken(response.data.token))
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch(fetchUser());
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(setFormErrors({errors: error.response.data}));
        })
    }
};

export const fetchUser = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(authLoading(true));
        const { userToken } = getState().auth;
        return axios.post(API.CURRENT_USER, null, {
            headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}` },
        }).then((response) => {
            const { id, name, username, email } = response.data.user;
            dispatch(setCurrentUser({current_user: { id, name, username, email }}));
            dispatch(authLoading(false));
        }).catch((error) => {
            if(error.response.status) {
                dispatch(logout());
            }
        });
    };
};

export const checkToken = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const token = await getToken();
        const { userToken } = getState().auth;
        if (token || userToken) {
            dispatch(loginSuccess());
            dispatch(fetchUser());
        }
    };
}

export const setToken = token => localStorage.setItem('token', token);
export const getToken = () => localStorage.getItem('token');
export const clearToken = () => localStorage.removeItem('token');
```